# Need help in making a signup page

Tags: php

I'm triyng to make a login/signup page. But I'm facing a problem in the signup page. This is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();


 if (isset($_REQUEST['register']))
 {
 $username = $_REQUEST['user'];
 $pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];

 if ($username=="")
 {
     die("<br /> You Forgot to type in the Username for the user !<br><br>Redirecting back to the previous page...<meta HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='3; URL=signup.php'> ");
 }
 if ($pass=="")
 {
     die("<br /> You Forgot to type in the Password for the user !<br><br>Redirecting back to the previous page...<meta HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='3; URL=signup.php'> ");
 }

 $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
 if(!$connect)
 {
     die(mysql_error());
 }

 $select_db = mysql_select_db("new");
 if(!$select_db)
 {
     die(mysql_error());
 }

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password) 
              VALUES ('$username', '$pass') ");
 } 

 ?>
```

I want to put a limit on username, like username already exists. With this code there can be so many signups with same username. So i want to put a limit on that.

Comment: for starters, this `error_reporting(0);` doesn't help you, this does `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` - Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Google "if row exists mysql" - you can also set a unique constraint.

Comment: you'll need to write some sql to check the db for usernames. you'll also want to make sure that you've set `username` in your database to a unique index. theres tons of info out there on this exact issue already out there

Comment: plain text passwords; remind me not to register there. *"Kids these days."*

Comment: Please learn using proper tutorials which are more than abundant on the Internet. This isn't a school or a "show me how to" site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sqlstr = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
if (!$res = $connect->query($sqlstr)) {
    trigger_error('Error in query ' . $connect->error);
} else {
    if ($res->num_rows == 0) {
       //username does not exist yet
    } else {
       //username exists already
    }
}
```

This'll check your database for the given user

Comment: can you please write the full code?